# An online tree of life with extinct species present?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, database, extinction

There are awesome online phylogenetic trees such as OneZoom.

But they all only list living species.

I want to see dinosaurs between birds and crocodiles.

I wanna see that humans are reptiliomorphs and eupelycosaurs.

species.wikimedia.org seems to contain this info, but it's not presented in a navigable tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

The tree of life project is your best bet, its not 100% complete but it is more complete than any other project I have ever seen, and unlike most actually includes many if not most extinct taxa. http://tolweb.org/tree/phylogeny.html

It also includes citation and brief descriptions of links and groups to make it easier. Some extinct lineages suffer from unresolved phylogenies but many of those are in constant flux or are actually unresolved in the fine scale so I can't blame them, especially considering they were originally based entirely on genetics, and is updated constantly.

Answer (score -1):

Had this same question, and after a lot of digging, came up with this http://lifemap.univ-lyon1.fr/explore.html

Very cool tool!!

Comment: cool but dinosaurs are not included other than a footnote.

Comment: A link is not an answer in terms of SE Biology. Please finish the [Tour] and read the help on answering questions.